# How can I use a segue with Navigation Controller at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

Since I can't find anything about this case, I guess I'm doing something wrong, but not sure why.

I have:
`NavigationController -> (root view) UIViewController (1st) -> (here is a segue) -> UITabBarController (2nd) -> UIViewController`

I want to make segue from `1st UIView` to `2nd UIView` while pushing `2nd` into Navigation Controller stack.

When I'm doing pushViewController inside prepareForSegue

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "mySegue") {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(segue.destinationViewController, animated: true)
        }
}`

I've got exception

> Application tried to present modally an active controller

(which is obvious, because I made `push` with nav controller and then segue trying to present the same view again)

How can I use a segue with Navigation Controller at the same time?

Thanks!

UPD. As noted in answers, deprecated Segue type "Push" (not a "Show (e.g. Push)") works exactly as I want, but it's deprecated... Is there any "good" way?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using storyboards to setup the segues, you just the segue type to 'Push' and it will push it from the nearest UINavigationController ancestor. You just need to call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifierHere")` and the Navigation Controller will push it.

After you call this, the Current View Controller will call `prepareForSegue` to set up the next View Controller to be presented. You are getting the error because you  are trying to get the navigation controller to push the same view controller that is already trying to be presented.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: > You just need to call self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifierHere") -> It doesn't work for me. New view appears, but as simple view, not as with Nav Controller.

Comment: In the storyboard, when you click the segue, is it set to Push?

Comment: It's set to "Show (e.g. Push)", and simple "Push" listed as "Deprecated". Hmm, and this deprecated "Push" works exactly as I wanted... But I don't like "deprecated" state in this case :-) Is there any new way to do the same?